# Find the linear dependence using the rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

My attempt:
The only thing that I know is rotating $[c_1 , c_2 ]^T$ by an angle $\theta$ in the counter-clockwise direction is the same as multiplying the rotation matrix by $[c_1 , c_2 ]^T$. How to use this to find the linear dependence between $y$ and $x$?

Comment: Is the > symbol in your expression for $y supposed to be there?

Comment: @Semiclassical, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, all you have done is multiply by a rotation matrix of angle $\theta$ in the two dimensional subspace spanned by $u$ and $v$. If we extend the orthonormal basis $(u,v)$ of this subspace to a (if you want, orthonormal) basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $Q$ does not affect the other basis vectors, and we may write the matrix as
$$
    Q = \begin{bmatrix}
    R_\theta & 0 \\
0 & I_{m-2 \times m-2}
\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
     \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
in the basis where the first two vectors are $(u,v)$.